# grype not using custom config.yaml

Tags: docker, grype

I use grype security scanner to scan my docker image.
I run grype itself also as docker container with the following command:

```
docker run -v ./grype-config:/config -e "DOCKER_CONFIG=/config" anchore/grype:latest -c "/config/config.yaml" my-own-image
```

In the current directoy a have a sub directory `grype-config` which contains the file `config.yaml` which has the following content:

```
# the output format of the vulnerability report (options: table, json, cyclonedx)
# same as -o ; GRYPE_OUTPUT env var
output: "json"

ignore:
  # We can make rules to match just by vulnerability ID:
  - vulnerability: CVE-2023-5156
  - vulnerability: CVE-2023-4813
  - vulnerability: CVE-2023-4806
  - vulnerability: CVE-2016-20013
  - vulnerability: CVE-2022-27943
  - vulnerability: CVE-2022-27943
```

The output from grype is the following:

```
NAME        INSTALLED              FIXED-IN  TYPE  VULNERABILITY   SEVERITY
libc6       2.35-0ubuntu3.4                  deb   CVE-2023-5156   Medium
libc6       2.35-0ubuntu3.4                  deb   CVE-2023-4813   Low
libc6       2.35-0ubuntu3.4                  deb   CVE-2023-4806   Low
libc6       2.35-0ubuntu3.4                  deb   CVE-2016-20013  Negligible
libgcc-s1   12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04            deb   CVE-2022-27943  Low
libstdc++6  12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04            deb   CVE-2022-27943  Low
```

Obviously grype ignores my `config.yaml` as it uses the output format `table`, not the output format `json` set in `config.yaml`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: already solved I have to use an absoulute path for my host machine folder. Then it works :)